# How do we add gravitational and kinetic time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

How do we combine kinetic and gravitational time dilations.  Lets say that a fast rocket experiencing 5% kinetic time dilation passes near a black hole in a region of 10% gravitational time dilation. When viewed by a distant observer, does the rocket have a total of 5 + 10 = 15% time dilation?  Or is it 1.05 x 1.10 = 1.155 or 15.5% time dilation?

Comment: Hint: we want to combine two time ratios...

Comment: Think about the clock of an observer stationary at the rocket's position and how that clock compares to the rocket's clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> foolishmuse asked: *"does the rocket have a total of 5 + 10 = 15% time dilation?"*

In some weak field simplifications they use the + instead of the ×, but that is only a good approximation if both factors are very small.

> foolishmuse asked: *"Or is it 1.05 x 1.10 = 1.155 or 15.5% time dilation?"*

Right. The time dilation relative to the coordinate bookkeeper is

$$\rm  \frac{dt}{d\tau}= \gamma \ \sqrt{g^{tt}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} \ \sqrt{1-r_s/r}}$$

where $\rm v$ is the velocity relative to local and stationary rulers and clocks.

Comment: So that would indicate that if our rocket was to pass much closer to the black hole, where time dilation was 90%, then the rocket would face 1.05 x 1.90 = 1.995 or nearly stopped time.

Comment: 1.995 is not nearly stopped, that only a factor of 2.

Comment: I was thinking of 100% as being fully dilated, or completely stopped. Does that change your general answer?