# General Relativistic version of the Lorentz factor

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, metric-tensor, observers

In curved spacetime, the Lorentz factor is different than that in flat spacetime.

Is there any expression that gives the Lorentz factor for any arbitrary metric tensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, almost. It is not quite any arbitrary metric. It must be a metric with a time coordinate $t$. $$\frac{1}{\gamma}=\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{-\frac{ds^2}{c^2 dt^2}}$$ Where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor, $ds^2$ is the metric (spacelike signature), and $d\tau$ is the proper time along some timelike worldline.

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz factor is the same, but you divide it with the gravitational time dilation $\surd g_{\rm tt}$ to get the total time dilation relative to a field free observer far away from and stationary with respect to the dominant mass, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/757665/how-do-we-add-gravitational-and-kinetic-time-dilation/757668#757668).